# Differential backups of git repositories using git bundle

Tags: git, backup

I would like to know if it is possible to do differential backups of a git repository, using `git bundle` like this:

First time:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/me/myrepo
git bundle create base.bundle --all
```

Every time I want to create a differential bundle:

```
cd myrepo
git fetch --all # is this necessary? (because "git bundle" doesn't check remote)
git bundle create diff.bundle $(git rev-parse HEAD)..HEAD --all
```

My main question is if above method ensures that base.bundle and diff.bundle, when used together, **contain the complete repository right from repository creation up until the point when diff.bundle was taken, including branches, tags**, and whatever else there may be in a git repo that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two commands work fine to create a base bundle.  However, your second group of commands won't do the right thing.  You *do* want the `git fetch` (`--all` is needed only if you have multiple remotes), but you want the newly created differential bundle to be done with "negative refspecs" for every ref that was a *positive* refspec in the previous bundle.  That is:

```
git bundle create diff.bundle $(git rev-parse HEAD)..HEAD --all
```

is clearly wrong for two reasons:

1. The inner `git rev-parse HEAD` uses the *current* `HEAD`, which may not be correct;
2. If the previous bundle (initial or previous differential) used `refs/heads/br1`, `refs/heads/br2`, `refs/tags/t1`, `refs/remotes/origin/r1`, and `refs/remotes/origin/r2` as its positive refspecs via `--all`, you need negative refspecs that will produce each hash ID from all of the positive refspecs.

The easiest way to fix both of these is to:

1. have the initial sequence end with `git rev-parse --all` with output saved somewhere;
2. for creating a new differential bundle, use `^$hash` for each hash ID listed in the saved output from the last save;
3. after creating the new differential bundle, use `git rev-parse --all` again to get the positive refspec hash IDs.

So you'll end up with something along these lines:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/me/myrepo
git bundle create $HOME/b/base.bundle --all
git rev-list --all > $HOME/b/hashes
```

followed by:

```
cd myrepo
git fetch  # --all if needed, but per the above there's just one remote
git bundle create $HOME/b/diff.bundle $(sed s/^/^/ < $HOME/b/hashes) --all
git rev-list --all > $HOME/b/hashes
```

Warning: this is entirely untested.  I'm also assuming that *each* `diff.bundle` is an increment to the *previous* `diff.bundle` here, i.e., these each need to be saved separately.

(You're probably best off using real backup software anyway, but this is likely to work.)

Comment: This is very instructive - thanks a lot! Doing `git rev-list --all > $HOME/b/hashes` after every fetch/bundle-create makes it an *incremental backup* though. I'm just mentioning this, because my question was about *differential backups*. This is good to know, however and I can just omit that step to do differential backups.

Comment: I hadn't heard this "differential backups" term before, so I assumed it was an odd translation for "incremental backups", but yes, if you just want to replace a single incremental backup over and over, that's the way to do it.

Comment: I think both incremental backup and differential backup are common terms, in fact each one has a wikipedia page of their own.

Comment: Interesting. [The page for differential backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_backup) mentions that Oracle "leverages a backward description", i.e., not everyone actually uses these words the same way. It looks like this terminology began to be used in the early 2010s (which puts it well after I learned these things; we used a hybrid scheme that incorporates both features but called it only "incremental" backup).